# Javascript hoisting and variable assignment (with no declaration)

Tags: javascript, hoisting

Looking at [MDN's introduction to JavaScript, Grammar and Types section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types) -  one reads:

> ### Declaring variables
>
> You can declare a variable in three ways:
>
> - With the keyword var. For example, var x = 42. This syntax can be    used to declare both local and global variables.
> - By simply assigning    it a value. For example, x = 42. This always declares a global    variable. It generates a strict JavaScript
>     warning. You shouldn't use    this variant.
> - With the keyword let. For example, let y = 13. This    syntax can be used to declare a block scope local variable. See    Variable scope
>     below.

The following code snippet would seem to fit the "by simply assigning it a value" scenario, meaning the variable should be treated as global.

```
(function(){
   console.log(myVar);
   //the following will throw a ReferenceException error
   //myVar = 10;

   //the following will not, and I can understand it following the defintion of the behavior of using `var` keyword
   //var myVar = 10;
})();
```

But running the code will generate a ReferenceException when `myVar` is commented, and undefined when not. I would expect it to generate undefined in both cases, since if `myVar` is a global variable (per definition), than javascript's variable hoisting would make it known before reaching `console.log(myVar);`

What is the explanation behind such behavior ? (the behavior I described is what I get when trying it in my firefox's console, but running it in `jsfiddle` will not throw an error).

Are self-executing functions an exception to hoisting ?

Comment: jsfiddle produces the ReferenceError for me in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Implicit global variable creation (when you don't actually declare it, but just assign to it) is NOT hoisted.  It happens inline where the assignment occurs.  Thus, when you try to read the variable, it does not exist yet and that is an error.  `var` or `let` declarations are hoisted.

Comment: @jfriend00: oh, jfriend00 is the first here to hint at something that explains it (at least for me). This would make it the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> the "by simply assigning it a value" scenario

You are *reading* the value, not assigning it

> if myVar is a global variable (per definition),

It isn't.

`myVar` is:

- *a variable scoped to the function* if the function contains `var myVar` (or `function myVar () { ... }`, or it is listed as a parameter in the function definition).
- *a variable scoped to the block* if the block contains `let myVar`
- *a global variable* if a value has been assigned to it previously and neither of the above conditions are true.

Since you haven't assigned a value, it isn't a global. Since none of the above conditions are true, it isn't any kind of variable, so you get a reference error.

---

Regarding your comment:

> I left my var when I meant var in the scenario I am trying to depict. Updated question.

… and [the edit to which you refer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36968108/revisions):

Commented out code is not evaluated. Having a comment that uses the keyword `var` doesn't do anything.

---

Regarding your further edits.

You get a reference error if you try to read a variable before it has been declared.

`var` statements (and function declarations) are hoisted so a variable declared with those methods can be read anywhere in the function.

Assignments are not hoisted. A global variable created implicitly by assignment (which is generally not considered to be best practise and is banned in strict mode) can't be read before the value is assigned.

Comment: oops, my mistake, I left var myVar when I meant myVar only in the scenario I am trying to depict. Updated question.

Comment: *You are reading the value, not assigning it* -  means that mdn's definition is problematic, does it not ? MDN states it is an assignment. And an assignment cannot be done without a prior declaration. Hence the confusion.

Comment: Quentin, pay attention to my 1st comment, I originally posted an incorrect version of the code. I refer to the version with the line commented out, and other with it as "var myVar".

Comment: @Veverke — Your edited code only changed the contents of a comment. Comments aren't treated as code. That's the entire point of comments.

Comment: You are right, I added to the confusion, updated the question again. I left now the 2 versions of the statement I intended to, originally. Running one will throw an error, the other, not. The working one I can understand as it follows from the definition of the behavior of using the `var` keyword to declare a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Since my comment seemed to help explain it to you, I will turn it into an answer:

Implicit global variable creation (when you don't actually declare it, but just assign to it) is NOT hoisted.  The variable creation happens inline at the moment the assignment occurs.

Thus, when you try to read the variable, it does not exist yet and that is an error.

`var` or `let` declarations are hoisted to the top of their appropriate scope.

---

All of this should hopefully help explain why you should just run in `strict` mode where implicit global creation is illegal and not allowed and triggers an immediate error.  It's basically evil.  A simple typo misspelling a variable may not trigger an error when you really want it to.

Comment: I singled your comment out because the other answer does not touch this - and this alone seems to be the answer, to me. Unfortunately the versions of the question I posted before you came were confusing and not reflected the current scenario - which is what I wanted to ask, so Quentin perhaps was not aware of the real question.

Comment: Although you were the one to add the solution first, will pick quentin's answer for his efforts - after he included this in his as well.